# Control cache when using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, caching

When using jQuery (specially on jquerymobile) it may be a good thing to keep some data on the device itself, rather than reloading it every time (for example news). Therefore I would like to use the built in ajax cache control. But the thing is, that I am not sure how to control the time periode for which the content is stored. I found no answer on the client side and came up to use the PHP-Headers like

```
Cache-Control: max-age=3600, must-revalidate
```

Is that a good way or should (and can) it be done on the client side? If client side, does anybody know a good piece of code illustrating the mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thing the server side is THE place to control the caching. You don't need to put logic inside php, you could also put it in .htaccess for some file types or based on directory.

Good article about cache control [Scaling PHP applications with Varnish](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-varnish/index.html), it's primary focus is on implementing Varnish inside project but it explains clijent side caching process as well, just read the "The cache-control header" section.